# user cannot access saved customization in OBIEE

Tags: obiee

One of our user want to save her current filter selections of report using "save current customization" on BI. But its giving error as **access denied for user to path /users//<>**.
She also complaints that her previously saved customisations are missing after recent deployment.

I understand that, its related to some user permission but not aware how to resolve it via analytics.

Can anybody suggest anything on this?

Comment: Would be good to know which exact version you are talking about...

Comment: I am using OBI  11.1.1.9.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"after recent deployment" .... So let me guess you overwrote her /users/HerName folder with the one from a different environment. And since 11.1.1.9 still uses GUIDs - guess what you probably just really messed up her folder and those of all users.

Edit: Refreshing user GUIDs : https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/biee/BIESC/privileges.htm#BIESC721

Comment: so is there any way through which we can get atleast user permission back as previous?

Comment: If I decide to give permission to individual user for saving customization, apart from  Save Customizations  option from Administration, do I need to change/update anything else?

Comment: You mean security privileges-wise?

Comment: I mean...how can I assign ' customization' related permission to a single user?specifically in this case when the user is getting error as 'path not found'.

Comment: I still dont see what you mean. Assigning the right to save customizations happens over web catalog privileges in Administration -> Manage Privileges.